# How to get distinct users with daily transactions

Tags: mysql, report, reporting

I have two table User and transactions where transaction table has user id

> UserID | UserName
>
> TransactionID | UserID | TransactioDate

I need to get number of distinct users that transact daily within a timeframe, i.e. users with txns everyday in a certain timeframe.

I can get distinct user for each day,

```
SELECT t.TransactioDate, COUNT(DISTINCT u.UserID) 
FROM user u 
INNER JOIN transaction t ON u.UserID = t.UserID AND t.TransactioDate BETWEEN '2018-01-13' AND '2018-02-12' 
GROUP BY CAST(t.TransactioDate AS DATE) 
ORDER BY t.TransactioDate
```

but i was wondering how to get users with txns everyday in a certain timeframe.

Comment: Is the column really named `TransactioDate` (with no `n` at the end of `Transaction`)?

Answer (score 0):

Join it with a subquery that counts the number of distinct days that each user has transactions, and returns the ones where this count is the same as the number of days in the time period.

```
SELECT DATE(t.TransactioDate) AS date, COUNT(DISTINCT u.UserID) 
FROM user u 
INNER JOIN transaction t ON u.UserID = t.UserID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT userID
    FROM transaction
    WHERE TransactioDate BETWEEN '2018-01-13' AND '2018-02-12' 
    GROUP BY userID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE(transactioDate))) = DATEDIFF('2018-02-12', '2018-01-13') + 1
) AS t1 ON t1.userID = u.userID
WHERE t.TransactioDate BETWEEN '2018-01-13' AND '2018-02-12' 
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY t.TransactioDate
```